# FOR EACH ROW in trigger causing a syntax error MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, syntax, triggers

I have the follow code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `po_history_update` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `purchase_orders` 
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO purchase_order_status_histories (
    purchase_order_id,
    old_status_id,
    old_status_date,
    current_status_id,
    current_status_date,
    user_id,
    duration,
    created_at,
    updated_at
  ) VALUES (
    new.id,
    old.status_id,
    old.status_changed_date,
    new.status_id,
    new.status_changed_date,
    new.user_id,
    DATEDIFF(old.status_changed_date, new.status_changed_date),
    now(),
    now()
  )
```

This gives me a syntax error but it works without `FOR EACH ROW` but I do not know why. It was working until I added more columns and I only have one statement, so I should not need to use DELIMITER or BEGIN... END, right?

Any assistance very welcome.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Cannot reproducte it: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rc2ZQJzZ8FnqPygPKrPqSV/0

Comment: Is is single statement or part of larger script?

Comment: 'so I should not need to use DELIMITER or BEGIN... END, right?' - correct.